# DataModel and DataModelSelection in Seam problem

Tags: ajax, jsf, grid, seam, datamodel

I wolud like use *DataModel* and *DataModelSelection* annotations in my managing component.

```
@Name("myComponent")
@Scope(CONVERSATION)
public class MyComponent {

   @DataModel
   private List<Item> myDataModel;


   @DataModelSelection
   @Out(required=false) 
   private Item selectedItem;


   ....

}
```

Lets assume that I want to make a modal panel in which I would like to show the selected item data.
Unfortunatelly the property 'selectedItem' which is annotated *DataModelSelection*  is null in modal panel....

```
 <rich:dataGrid value="#{myDataModel}" var="something">
    ....
    <a4j:commandButton oncomplete="show my edit panel" ..../>
    ....
 </rich:dataGrid>

 <rich:modalPanel>
    ....
    <h:inputText value="myComponent.selectedItem"/>
 </rich:modalPanel>
```

Is there any possible way to use the selected data outside the data grid?

Another thing is that I can not use the "myComponent.myDataModel" in the *dataGrid* **value** property, but simply *myDataModel*. In other cases it doesn't work fine what may be problematic if I would like to use some class for base to the other.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use EL syntax so; use  `<h:inputText value="#{selectedItem}"/>` instead of `<h:inputText value="myComponent.selectedItem"/>`